# bootstrap tab collapse/expand

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a tab in bootstrap with collapsible tab pages and up/down arrows.

[image]

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">tab 1</a></li>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <p>Tab 1 content.</p>
   </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <p>Tab 2 content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE
I want tabs to be toggable so the tab expands or collapses when I click it again.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create your HTML like this,

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">tab 1
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span> 
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span></a>
   </li>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">tab 2
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span></a>
   </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <p>Tab 1 content.</p>
   </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <p>Tab 2 content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then CSS like this,

```
.nav-tabs>li>a>.glyphicon.glyphicon-menu-down{display:block;}
.nav-tabs>li>a>.glyphicon.glyphicon-menu-up{display:none;}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a>.glyphicon.glyphicon-menu-down{display:none;}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a>.glyphicon.glyphicon-menu-up{display:block;}
```

This might work as you wanted. But you might have to style it according to your need.

**Here is a working example I made - http://www.bootply.com/2cSkBhK32r**

Comment: Thank you. It's possible tab pages to be both collapsed initially and arrows to be next to header (not bellow)?

Comment: Just change `display:block` to `display:inline-block`in the CSS.